# ubuntu upstart - how to set global nofile limit?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, upstart

ubuntu 12.04

I have change the setting:

```
 /etc/security/limits.conf
 *               soft    nofile          65000
 *               hard    nofile          65000
```

but cat /proc/{PID}/limits:

```
Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units     
Max open files            1024                 4096                 files
```

I found the problem. Upstart has a bug that causes it to ignore limits set in **/etc/security/limits.conf**. These links describe the bug and a workaround.

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/upstart/+bug/938669
- http://bryanmarty.com/blog/2012/02/10/setting-nofile-limit-upstart/
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19995855/increase-max-open-files-for-ubuntu-upstart-initctl

Now the question is, how to set a global nofile limit because i don't want to set nofile limit in every upstart script which i need.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The Upstart behavior is as specified and is not a bug - services are bound by their own configuration and not by the security limits (which bind user processes for which there is no other definition - hence why it is *security* limits).

There was some work done to implement a ["global configuration" defaults file for Upstart](https://code.launchpad.net/~lnykryn/upstart/global-configuration) but that seems to have been neglected (possibly due to non-commitment from Upstart developers).

IMO your best choice is to create an override file with just the `limit nofile` directive and copy it to override all existing upstart services. Something like this:

```
for file in /etc/init/*.conf
  do echo "limit nofile 65000 65000" > "${file%%.conf}.override"
done
```